# How to add sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError as side effect to mock objects?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-mock

I am testing a function that needs a mock object. This object might raise IntegrityError so I am adding this error as side effect to the mock object

```
def test_(self, mock_object):
        mock_object.side_effect = IntegrityError
```

This is somehow not correct as it raises an exception saying `__init__() takes at least 4 arguments (1 given)`
What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: As always, include the full traceback, not just the error. In this case it would've been obvious then that the `IntegrityError.__init__` is failing, since the mock object is trying to construct it incorrectly.

Comment: The error message already tells that in this case. The problem at hand is how to construct the error correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Just build a one-line function raising an integrity error, and add that as the side-effect:

```
x = Mock()

def b():
    raise IntegrityError('Mock', 'mock', 'mock')

x.side_effect = b
x()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to raise the exception in a separate function. Instead you can just do this:

```
mock_object.method_to_mock = MagicMock(
    side_effect=IntegrityError(MagicMock(), MagicMock(), MagicMock()))
```